# Domain class creating error when version changed to next Grails version

Tags: grails

I downloaded GGTS. Grails version is 2.3.7.I changed to Grails version 2.2.4.At the time, when I create the domain class it generate error.If anyone know help me , please. Creating Grails project with 2.3.7 ver is ok. 2.2.4 is problem.

```
{ Starting process on NDMM0245-PC/192.168.10.178
  Loading Grails 2.2.4
  | Configuring classpath
  | Downloading: tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42.jar
  ..........
}
```

after loading a long time.Error is below..

```
 'create domain class ' has encountered error.
  The command Grails command (project) was terminated because it didn't produce new product output produced so far.
  ...
  See menu Windows>>Preferences>>Grails>>Launch
```

So, I configured In Preference >>Grails lunch>>
  I add the 'Grails 2.2.4' variable and value to 'Grails 2.2.4 directory'.

Comment: I could solve that problem by downloading and adding the following jar files to Grails Project from Build path.(1)tomcat-embed-core-7.0.42(2)tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.42   Thank to All.

Comment: Please don't deface your own questions; doing so always does more harm than good

Comment: @user3588466 - your nonsensical edit has been rolled back. There's no such thing as "blocking" a question, as the complete history sticks around. Why would you even do that?

Answer (score 0):

You have to download the Grails version you want to use and then "Add..." it in Preferences > Groovy > Grails.

An easier way to manage your Grails versions is [gvm](http://gvmtool.net). You can install this tool and run

```
gvm install grails 2.2.4
```

which will install Grails in the following directory

```
~/.gvm/grails/2.2.4
```

which you can then "Add..." to GGTS.

Comment: I already added the Grails in Window>>Preferences.Thank Ken for your answer.By the way what can GVM can do?Guide me where to download this and how to do configuration?

Comment: You don't add a new Grails version at the Grails Launch preference page. Unless I've misunderstood you, I don't think you've done it correctly. You might want to reread my answer very closely.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure your grails package for 2.2.4 is not corrupted or check
   the size
2. Do a **grails maven clean** after grails install on terminal to avoid conflicts of cache
3. Check you **ALL** environment variable if you are pointing directly to your grails 2.2.4 directory.Avoid other **grails 2.3.7**
   like environment settings if possible.
4. Check if u have the right grails install or configuration by issuing this command
   `grails version`
5. Check your GGTS if its pointing to grails 2.2.4 on Perefernce ->Groovy->Grails or add it there.
6. After all do a `Grails -> Referesh Dependency` and `Clean and Build` on GGTS.

Alloha!!